# Spherical Harmonics Interpolation

Tags: reference-request, interpolation, spherical-harmonics

I am interested in interpolation using spherical harmonics.

I feel like I searched all Google pages containing key words of this subject. Therefore I want to ask if anyone is familiar with this, and could recommend material to me (like papers, books or webpages) where I can read about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last chapter or two of Dym and McKean's *Fourier Series and Integrals* addresses this to some degree, but it's heavy going.

In general, if you want to approximate a function $f: S^2 \subset \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ by a sum
$$
f(x, y, z) \approx \sum c_i h_i(x, y, z)
$$
you can find the coefficients $c_i$ by computing
$$
c_i = \int_{S^2} f(x, y, z) h_i(x, y, z) ~dA
$$
just as you compute Fourier coefficients by integrating over the circle. This works because the harmonics $h_i$ are an orthogonal set of functions (with respect to the inner product "integrate $fg$ over $S^2$"); you're really just doing orthogonal projections onto the axes of a subspace of the space of all integrable functions on the sphere.

Comment: Wow...accepted after 10 months. I'm baffled but pleased. Did it take a long time to decide that the answer was worth something? Of was it just the lack of competition? :)